# Client-side initialization in Next.js with Static HTML Export

Tags: next.js, react-i18next, static-html

We're developing a Next.js app using react-i18next for localization. We're using `next export` ([Static HTML Export](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export)). The react-i18next library requires [initialization code](https://react.i18next.com/getting-started#basic-sample), and I'm not sure where to call that.

(We're not using next-i18next, as [that does not work with next export](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/issues/1048).)

Right now I have the initialization in a separate module (outside of pages/). If I import that module into pages/_app.tsx and run the build script (`next build && next export`), the build hangs. When I hit Ctrl-C, I get:

> Error: setRawMode EIO

The same thing happens if I try to import it from a [custom Document](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document).

My current workaround is to import the initialization module in pages/index.tsx - that works, but feels wrong.

The project uses TypeScript and yarn v1, and was scaffolded with `create-next-app` (in case any of that is relevant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Custom App](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) import does appear to be the correct place for client-side initialization code (inferred based on [Custom Polyfills](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/supported-browsers-features#custom-polyfills)).

The issue is that an _app module will execute when `next build && next export` is called. Asynchronous calls (i18next-http-backend in my case) can cause the build script to hang.

The fix is to wrap the initialization code in:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  // initialization code - will only run on client side
}
```

Based on https://flaviocopes.com/nextjs-server-client-code/

This does mean that the initialization code won't run for Jest tests either, but [react-i18next can be mocked](https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing).